# WPF Different Frame Navigation Animation For Buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, navigation, devexpress

I build a WPF application with the help of Devexpress component in witch I have a frame that I use to navigate through various pages.

What I want to do is for some buttons to have different animation.
For example my main frame animation is slide vertical to the right but I have a button that when I press it I want the animation to be slide vertical to the left and an other one that I want to slide Horizontal down.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the view transition animation type via the [NavigationFrame.AnimationType](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfWindowsUINavigationFrame_AnimationTypetopic) property.
Related help article: [Navigation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument15023)

Comment: I tried this but that way all my navigation animations change. I only want this to happen when a certain button is pressed